# Passing an empty value in XML with XSD pattern validation

Tags: xml, api, xsd, xsd-validation, tibco

I'm trying to send the following XML request with an empty `InvestorID` field but getting an error back with the response:

> "module does not conform to the activity output schema. The initial value ' ' is not valid with respect to the simple type definition InvestorIDType"

```
  <tns:Investor>
    <tns:InvestorId/>
    <tns:firstName>FirstName</tns:firstName>
    <tns:lastName>LastName</tns:lastName>
    <tns:dateOfBirth>1970-01-01</tns:dateOfBirth>
  </tns:Investor>
```

Should the pattern value `([0-9]{10})?` of my simple type allow for an empty field? (as shown below)

```
<simpleType name="InvestorIDType">
    <restriction base="string">
        <pattern value="([0-9]{10})?" />
    </restriction>
</simpleType>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the pattern value allows for an empty field.

The original document successfully validates against this schema (assuming that `tns` is bound to the namespace `http://www.example.com`):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns="http://www.example.com"
  targetNamespace="http://www.example.com"
  elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <xs:simpleType name="InvestorIDType">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:pattern value="([0-9]{10})?" />
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:element name="Investor">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="InvestorId" type="InvestorIDType"/>
                <xs:element name="firstName" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element name="lastName" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element name="dateOfBirth" type="xs:date"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

However, the error message mentions `' '`, which is not empty: it is a string containing one space character. Maybe the error could come from somewhere else in the file, with something like this:

```
<tns:InvestorId> </tns:InvestorId>
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm new to xml/xsd and just needed some confirmation on wherever my pattern would allow for an empty field. I'll look into if possibly it is passing a space character in and I haven't realised